# mypy doesn't warn about instantiating pure virtual class

Tags: python, mypy

I have an abstract class that specifies a pure virtual method `run`:

```
class Father:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 800
    def run(self, s: str) -> int:
        pass

class Son(Father):
    def walk(self, i: int) -> int:
        return self.i+i+800

s = Son()
```

When I run `mypy` no warnings are issued, why?

Comment: See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2350 .

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that `mypy` treats functions and methods with empty bodies as the word of truth since that is how stub files are defined. The issue I linked is proposing a fix for this, however, it's still open and the last activity was in 2020.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example doesn't have an abstract class or a pure virtual method (which, strictly speaking, isn't a thing in Python; it'd just be an abstract method).  It has two standard classes in a hierarchy, and the `run` function is a regular function.

If you want an abstract method, you'll have to mark it as such [using the bits and bobs in the `abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/abc.html#module-abc).

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Father(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 800

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, s: str) -> int:
        ...


class Son(Father):
    def walk(self, i: int) -> int:
        return self.i + i + 800


s = Son()
```

This results in

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Son with abstract method run
```

at runtime and

```
error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "Son" with abstract attribute "run"
```

at mypy time.

If you don't care for the runtime check, don't derive `Father` from `ABC`.